# React native Library to take bitmap

Tags: react-native, bitmap

I am  Working on  react native camera library to taking bitmap.

For example, when we capture a image it return image path, height, width etc.

Instead of these i  need bitmap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to achieve what you're looking to do is likely going to be to use the Native UI Components API for [iOS](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-components-ios.html) and [Android](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-components-android.html) to implement a custom native image view that applies the effects you are looking for.

React Native doesn't give the option of accessing access the raw bitmap data of the React Native  (aka. RCTImage) component.